# Play Framework 2.2.1 concatenate variable in template while iterating

Tags: java, variables, loops, fill, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to iterate over a List with Person objects to build a table.
Each row is a Person entry.
A Person has some general infos like name e.g. - and an ID.
I need all IDs concatenated as String to call another function (wich will export those Persons to CSV).

So what I try to achieve is a variable inside the iteration to concatenate with all IDs like `12,13,14,346,74,12`to pass over to the `href="/export?ids=@ids`

```
@for(person <- personList) {
 <tr><td>@person.name</td></tr>
}
```

Inside this loop I need to concantenate all `@person.id`elements.

I'm using Play for Java so no Scala examples please.

Thanks
msl

Comment: What kind of Array and function?

Comment: edited the question - I need to concatenate a variable. not to fill an array. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said no scala but still it would be the easiest:

```
personList.map(_.id).mkString(",")
```

The templates are written in scala anyways, so I guess it won't do any harm to pick up some scala along the way.

If you're not happy with this solution, transform the `personList` in the controller and pass down the created `String` of ids.